# thumbanail create function error with php version 5.2.9

Tags: php, thumbnails

My servers php version is 5.2.9,

i'm uploading some pictures into my site, i want to create thumbnails of that images,

but none of the thumbnail create functions are working in my site.

like imagecreatefromjpeg(),
imagecreatetruecolor(),

everything is saying undefined function..

what will be reason for this.

Is the functions are not supported in php version 5.2.9

How can i solve this problem.

Can anyone help to fix this issue.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: can you use like @imagecreatefromjpeg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the [GD library](http://php.net/gd) is not installed. Are you on a shared host, or an own server?

Comment: how can i know whether gd library enabled or not?
i have searched in my phpinfo, but nothing showed like gd

Comment: You should see a heading named "GD" with "GD Support  Enabled". I'm sure you don't have GD library now. Again: what OS are you using? Win32 or Linux? Are you able to install software on that server?

Comment: check phpinfo or as administrator to enable gd library to specific gd2